# React Auto RTL text inputs

Tags: reactjs, right-to-left

I want all my components using `input[type=text]` to get RTL or LTR direction based on user input automatically.

Back in old days(2 or 3 years ago) I used jQuery to select all these inputs and apply my script like [this](https://codepen.io/siamak/pen/rAmBb). But what is the best solution to implement this feature in React?

Answer (score 0):

build your wrapper around Input component and do your logic inside this component :) Then everywhere in the code use your `<CustomInput />` instead `<input ...>`.

EDIT:

enclosing a code example of wrapping input element:

```
import React from "react";

class CustomInput extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {onChange, ...otherProps} = this.props;
        // Please provide onChange callback to make this Input element "Controlled"
        // otherProps are there for things like default value etc. :)
        return(
            <input type="text" onChange={onChange} />
        );
    }

}

export default CustomInput;
```

and if you will not use any of the lifecycle methods you can even implement this component as a function

```
import React from "react";

const CustomInput = ({onChange, ...otherProps}) => (
    <input type="text" onChange={onChange} />;
);

export default CustomInput;
```

Comment: This is not a simple way. I have lots of inputs and I don't want to modify their code or component.